# Firebase: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app's `main.dart`, I ran the following code:

```
final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

I took the token and used it in my cloud function:

```
exports.notifyUserAddedToGroup = functions.firestore
    .document("groups/{groupDocID}/groupMembers/{groupMembersDocID}")
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      const FCMToken = `loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
      fcmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
      tokennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn`;
      const payload = {
        token: FCMToken,
        notification: {
          title: "Title",
          body: "Body",
        },
        data: {
          body: "data body",
        },
      };
      admin.messaging().send(payload)
          .then((response) => {
            console.info("##MyApp## function executed successfully");
            return {msg: "##MyApp## function executed succesfully"};
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.info("##MyApp## error in execution");
            console.log(error);
            return {msg: "##MyApp## error in execution"};
          });
    });
```

I then went to Firestore and added a document into the correct collection to trigger the cloud function. When I went to the google cloud console logs, I saw the following error:

```
The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token
```

Why is my token invalid if I just generated it a few minutes before triggering the cloud function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the hard coded FCM token in the function. I put the token in Firestore instead and queried it to use it in the function and it worked.